# Eizo radiforce g31 is mirrorring desktop in the same monitor

Tags: windows-7, display

I have an Eizo Med-X4900 connected to a Eizo RadiForce G31 monitor on windows 7.
The problem is that I get the desktop duplicated in the monitor, also the BIOS is mirrorred so i think it has nothing to do with the driver. The monitor is splited into two frames showing the desktop mirrorred.

It happens the same with a nvidia quadro fx 1800.

¿Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it has worked  the umpteenth time I have reinstalled the driver.
Thanks.